# Is it possible to warp a raster using -te in other projection?

Tags: clip, gdalwarp

I have some files in EPSG:4326 and some in "ESRI:102027".
I use warping with -te argument in EPSG:4326:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -t_srs srs -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -te_srs "EPSG:4326" $OUT/$file $OUT/${file}_test.tif
```

For files with EPSG:4326 the result is correct (srs=EPSG:4326), but for files with "ESRI:102027" (srs=ESRI:102027) I get a stripe with ll_x=xmin, ur_x=xmax (see the pic).
[image]

What's the matter? In fact I need "crop to cutline" but not to a shp layer, but to coordinates written as an array.
I would like to crop all these files undepending on their projection, but the window to crop to should be in  EPSG:4326

UPD: It emerged that in my gdalwarp (GDAL 3.5.3, released 2022/10/21) there is no -te_srs argument.. so...

UPD2: If I change arguments to:

```
-s_srs $T_SRS -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

it works, so it lets me create the target only in target projection

But how can I createtarget file in target projection different from one -te xmin ymin xmax ymax are described with?

UPD3: the full result of gdalmerge --help (which shows, that my version has no -te_srs option:

```
gdalwarp --help
Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
[-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* [-vshift |   -novshift]
[[-s_coord_epoch epoch] | [-t_coord_epoch epoch]]
[-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
[-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
[-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE] [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...]  [-wt Byte/Int16]
[-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha
[-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]
[-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]
[-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]
[-if format]* [-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]
[-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value] [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]*
[-doo NAME=VALUE]*
srcfile* dstfile

Available resampling methods:
near (default), bilinear, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos, average, rms,
mode,  max, min, med, Q1, Q3, sum.
```

UPD4: And now gdal writes me for

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -of GTiff -s_srs $T_SRS -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -te $tarray $OUT/${file}.map $OUT/${file}_test.tif
```

> ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-te'
> Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
> [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* [-vshift | -novshift]
> [[-s_coord_epoch epoch] | [-t_coord_epoch epoch]]
> [-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
> [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
> [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax]

Pay attention to the last []..
Whats? -te is also a wrong option (tarray is an array of xmin ymin xmax ymax)

Answer (score 1):

My test file "Pk50095.tif" is included into the demo data that comes with GeoServer. It is in EPSG:32633 but GDAL does not recognize the .prj file. Therefore -s_srs must be set explicitly for GDAL. The lower left corner of the selection box in EPSG:4326 is (13.1 46.73), and upper right corner  (13.2 46.83)

[image]

The command for warping image from EPSG:32633 into EPSG:32632 by defining the target extent in EPSG:4326 units is:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:32633 -t_srs EPSG:32632 -te 13.1 46.73 13.2 46.83 -te_srs EPSG:4326 Pk50095.tif 32632.tif
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Thus the answer is yes. It is possible to define the target extent for gdalwarp in other projection with the syntax that is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html.

Your GDAL version should have the option `-te_srs` because it was new in GDAL version 2.0 released in the summer of 2015 https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.0.0-News.

Comment: Pls, see UPD3, my version hasn't -te_srs option

Comment: What is your GDAL version `gdalinfo --version`? It seems that my GDAL 3.6.2 does not list the option either, but it works. You can try to find from the history when it disappeared https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdalwarp_bin.cpp.